# TKinter place the buttons very slowly

Tags: python, tkinter

TKinter place the buttons very slowly. My code puts a large number of buttons in the form of a table using already optimized loops. When you click on any button, it is destroyed and the code is executed in which the column and row of this button are needed. But this code works very slowly - it takes about 2 seconds to display a field of 30x30 buttons. I've optimized everything I could (set the values of the *side* and *y* variables so that they are not calculated many times) but it doesn't help.

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

class UI:
    def _setcell(row, column):
        pass
    def window(rows, columns, a):
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry(f"{rows*(a+6)}x{columns*(a+6)}")
        root.resizable(False, False)
        root.title("Tkinter window")
        
        field_frame = Frame(width=rows*(a*a), height=columns*(a*a), bg="#293133", colormap="new")
        field_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        field_frame.grid_propagate(False)
        pixelVirtual = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
        def btns():
            start_time = time.time()

            btnarr = []
            side = a+6
            for row in range(rows):
                rowl = []
                y=side*row
                for column in range(columns):
                    rowl.append(Button(field_frame, text="", image=pixelVirtual, height = a, width = a, command=
                    lambda row=row, column=column: [btnarr[row][column].place_forget(), __class__._setcell(row, column)]))
                    rowl[column].place(x=column*side, y=y)
                btnarr.append(rowl)
            
            print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

        btn_thread = threading.Thread(target=btns)
        btn_thread.start()



        root.mainloop()
UI.window(30, 30, 16)
```

Comment: You can avoid a lot of geometry management events by withdrawing the root window until you create everything. `root.wm_withdraw()` at the top and `root.wm_deiconify()` just before mainloop. However, for something with this many windows to be created you might do better to use a canvas and create lots of rectangles in the canvas instead. This avoids the creation of so many widgets. Canvas items are much lighter weight but can still be bound to events.

Comment: Have you tried removing the threading code? Threading adds overhead and tkinter doesn't work well in threads. When I remove the threading code the buttons appear in well under a second. You should also consider using `grid` rather than `place`, which will probably be more efficient code.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm added threading to already working code, so that during the loading of the field, the user can click on other elements and drag the window. Without threading, the program works exactly the same. I don't use **grid** because it automatically shifts elements when a row or column disappears.

Comment: @qazwsxedc: I don't know what you mean by grid shifting elements. It doesn't do that - once an element is in a specific row or column, that's where it stays until you explicitly move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great deal of micro management in your code. Tkinter is clever and can easily handle positioning and size of widgets. I've replaced pack and place with grid manager and removed threading as I couldn't find any reference to `btns`.

Here is a modified version of your code that works.

It takes about 10 seconds to display 900 buttons with images.
The image used is 131x136 and subsampled to 22x23 which allows all buttons to be visible on my monitor.

The addition of a blank image of equal dimensions and a change to `_setcell`
maintains button positioning and prevents annoying changes to overall UI size.

```py
from tkinter import *

filepath = "Arrow.gif"
blakpath = "Black.gif"

class UI:

    def _setcell(self, row, column):
        self.btnarr[row][column].config(
            image = self.blankVirtual, command = '')

    def window(self, rows, columns):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Tkinter window")       
        field_frame = Frame(self.root, bg="#293133", colormap="new")
        field_frame.grid(sticky = NSEW)
        self.pixelVirtual = PhotoImage(file = filepath).subsample(6,6)
        # w, h = self.pixelVirtual.width(), self.pixelVirtual.height()
        self.blankVirtual = PhotoImage(file = blakpath).subsample(6,6)

        btnarr = []
        for row in range(rows):
            rowA = []
            for column in range(columns):
                rowA.append(Button(field_frame, image = self.pixelVirtual))
                rowA[~0].grid(row = row, column = column, sticky = NSEW)
                rowA[~0]["command"] = lambda row = row, column = column: [self._setcell(row, column)]

            btnarr.append(rowA)

app = UI()
app.window(30, 30)
app.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But the grid() method changes the button field when a row or column is removed -  aligning it, and rowA[~0].place(x=column*16, y=row*16) does not work for some reason

Comment: I can see that when an entire row or column is removed the UI shrinks. A solution is to use `_setcell` to handle button change|removal instead of the lambda. I'll make a small change to my answer that will fix this.